# Move data between databases on two shared hosting accounts

Tags: php, mysql, hosting

I have two shared hosting accounts, each with a database of its own (its own cPanel login). Assuming these two databases have the same structure, what do I need to do in order to synchronize them?

The synchronization script would be on a domain connected with one of the hosting accounts. I know the MySQL/PHP for synchronizing databases that are on the same account is fairly simple, but what's confusing me here is how to access the database which is on different hosting?

This isn't a one-time thing, I need to be able to do this by clicking a button/link.

The only thing that comes to mind is having the remote database export everything to .csv files on a regular basis and have the script on the domain connected to the first database import everything,  but there's gotta be a better way?

In case this whole question is confusing, the gist of the problem is - is there a way to have a script on a domain access a database on a completely different shared hosting account?

Comment: Why dont you add a remote user to the database you want to transfer (<username>@<host>) and use it in your script, to access the data there?

Comment: @Efthymis not all hosters give up host names for DB servers.

Comment: @SergeiTulentsev you 're right. I was having my host in mind. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, **no**, there's no way.

Usually, hosting providers allow DB access only to `localhost` users. Meaning that script from another machine can't access it.

Also, what kind of synchronization is it? One-way or two-way? (but, I guess, this is out of scope here)

The only viable solution that comes to mind is some kind of dump/restore procedure.

**Example**:

- webserver `A` (source of data) defines an URL, by requesting which you can get dumped content of the DB
- webserver `B` (destination of data) defines a page with button 'Sync'.
- upon clicking the 'Sync' button, server `B` will fetch that URL from server `A`, receive A's data and merge it with its own.

**NOTE**

It is important to secure data export URL. In that script you can check, for example, IP of incoming request, or presence and correctness of "access_token" or whatever you like.

Comment: It should be two-way but I'd settle for one way. And what if I moved them to the same hosting provider? Would there be any problems then?

Comment: So, what do you think of my solution?

Comment: Where would this url be? Let's say the domains are domain1.com and domain2.com and the synch button should be on domain2.

Comment: Whatever you like (you'll have to write a script on domain1 that handles this URL and dumps the Db into response)

Answer (score 0):

Can you connect to the database via the SSL/SSH or PHP tunnel? If so, try Data Comparison tool in [dbForge Studio MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/).

Data Comparison tool will allow you to compare data between different databases. You may test it with a trial version.